# System message breaks mobile site layout

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

When a site has a "system message" shown (such as the message shown on recently launched beta sites, like [Vi/Vim](//vi.stackexchange.com)), the mobile layout suffers:

> [image: message]

Compare the above with how the mobile navigation bar normally looks:

> [image: normal]

Worse yet, a selected tab on the navigation bar is shown in white on white:

> [image: selected]

Observed in mobile Opera 27 on Android, and also in desktop Chrome 41 on Chrome OS, from where the screenshots are taken.

The problem is that  `<div class="system-message-container">` is positioned where the navigation bar is supposed to be; if it is  deleted, the normality is restored.

Comment: Yes, reproduced.

Comment: +1 for this as I posted the same (dupe accepted min ago) today. It's been over 5 months...

Comment: The. Bug. Is. Finally. Fixed. (because of the 10M banner on SO)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple CSS fix:

```css
.nav { clear: both }
```

P.S. You can currently [reproduce this bug on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303119/css-bug-with-selected-element-in-menu-on-mobile) by switching to the mobile view, thanks to the "ten million questions" announcement.  Here's a pair of screenshots showing the SO front page with and without this fix (taken using the Firefox dev tools, in responsive design mode):

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow mobile view with CSS bug]
   
[image: Screenshot of fixed Stack Overflow mobile view]